# Can't Install JCL in Delphi 11 CE

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, jvcl

I am trying to do a manual install of jcl since running Install.bat gives me the error: "This version of the product does not support command line compiling.". I tried to follow the documentation but i could not understand it.

```
Manual Installation
Although it is not recommended, a manual installation is possible. You will have to manually configure options for the library. That is done by modifying an included file.


For each tool you want to install the JCL in, repeat the following steps:

Open and edit included file to customize options:
For C++Builder 6: source\include\jclc6.inc
For Delphi 6: source\include\jcld6.inc
For Delphi 7: source\include\jcld7.inc
For Delphi 2005: source\include\jcld9.inc
For BDS 2006 (Delphi and C++Builder): source\include\jcld10.inc
For CodeGear RAD Studio 2007 (Delphi for Win32 and C++Builder): source\include\jcld11.inc
For Delphi 2009 and C++Builder 2009: source\include\jcld12.inc
For Delphi 2010 and C++Builder 2010: source\include\jcld14.inc
For Delphi XE and C++Builder XE: source\include\jcld15.inc
For Delphi XE2 and C++Builder XE2 Win32: source\include\jcld16win32.inc
For Delphi XE2 Win64: source\include\jcld16win64.inc
For Delphi XE3 and C++Builder XE3 Win32: source\include\jcld17win32.inc
For Delphi XE3 and C++Builder XE3 Win64: source\include\jcld17win64.inc
For Delphi XE4 and C++Builder XE4 Win32: source\include\jcld18win32.inc
For Delphi XE4 and C++Builder XE4 Win64: source\include\jcld18win64.inc
For Delphi XE5 and C++Builder XE5 Win32: source\include\jcld19win32.inc
For Delphi XE5 and C++Builder XE5 Win64: source\include\jcld19win64.inc
For Delphi XE6 and C++Builder XE6 Win32: source\include\jcld20win32.inc
For Delphi XE6 and C++Builder XE6 Win64: source\include\jcld20win64.inc
For Delphi XE7 and C++Builder XE7 Win32: source\include\jcld21win32.inc
For Delphi XE7 and C++Builder XE7 Win64: source\include\jcld21win64.inc
For Delphi XE8 and C++Builder XE8 Win32: source\include\jcld22win32.inc
For Delphi XE8 and C++Builder XE8 Win64: source\include\jcld22win64.inc
For Delphi 10 and C++Builder 10 Win32: source\include\jcld23win32.inc
For Delphi 10 and C++Builder 10 Win64: source\include\jcld23win64.inc
For Delphi 10.1 and C++Builder 10.1 Win32: source\include\jcld24win32.inc
For Delphi 10.1 and C++Builder 10.1 Win64: source\include\jcld24win64.inc
For Delphi 10.2 and C++Builder 10.2 Win32: source\include\jcld25win32.inc
For Delphi 10.2 and C++Builder 10.2 Win64: source\include\jcld25win64.inc
For Delphi 10.3 and C++Builder 10.3 Win32: source\include\jcld26win32.inc
For Delphi 10.3 and C++Builder 10.3 Win64: source\include\jcld26win64.inc
For Delphi 10.4 and C++Builder 10.4 Win32: source\include\jcld27win32.inc
For Delphi 10.4 and C++Builder 10.4 Win64: source\include\jcld27win64.inc
For Delphi 11 and C++Builder 11 Win32: source\include\jcld28win32.inc
For Delphi 11 and C++Builder 11 Win64: source\include\jcld28win64.inc
For FreePascal: source\include\jclfpc.inc
In the IDE, open and compile package Jcl.dpk (or Jcl.bpk for C++Builder) located in a subdirectory of the "packages" directory matching your version of the IDE. This package doesn't have to be installed since it doesn't provide any components.
If you want to install experts, open package JclBaseExpert.dpk and compile it, then you can install all the experts you want (packages are located in the same directory).
```

I also tried to compile JclPackagesD280.groupproj but i get the error : "[dcc32 Fatal Error] jcl.inc(416): F1026 File not found: 'jcld28win32.inc'". I know it says "For manual installations, copy and adjust jcl/source/include/jcl.template.inc" but i also couldn't understand that.

[image]

Edit : I managed to compile and install jcl after all like in the image by downloading jcl from the dauly build but now when i try to do the same for jvcl i get "JvCore.dpk(41): E2202 Required package 'Jcl' not found"

Comment: Have you added the necessary paths to the library search path in the options dialog?

Comment: *This version of the product does not support command line compiling."* is very clear. The CE version of Delphi does not include the command line compiler, which is required for building the JEDI packages manually. There's no workaround - the command line compiler is required, and CE does not include it and you can't get it from anywhere.

Comment: @KenWhite, Documentation says that a 'manual installation' involves using the IDE to compile the package.  The command-line compiler is required for _automated_ installation.

Comment: @Adel, if you haven't already found this, see if this helps: https://newsportal.delphi-jedi.org/article.php?id=1711&group=jedi.jcl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too was confused by the readme on manual installation as the custom ( for newer releases of Delphi CE ) files the readme refers to did not appear to exist in https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/tree/master

I continued hunting around and found that the Readme does not apply to the master but it does appy to the nightly archives which can be found here, you'll find your missing 'jcld28win32.inc' and other missing files in here :-

https://jcl.sourceforge.net/daily/